How should the USB footprint be placed on the PCB?
My aim is for the USB connector to take up as little space on the board as possible.
As long as the pins of the USB remain on the board surface, is it correct to place it with the back sticking out of the board, or should it be placed completely on the board?


What I want to ask is: Is there a special rule for placing the USB connector, or can we position it on the PCB like in these two pictures?
Datasheet

Apart from what you're asking: This footprint is for a bottom-mount connector, i.e. it goes on the bottom side of your PCB - unless you want to mount the PCB upside down, or want to make a device that doesn't follow USB design recommendations.

What does the datasheet say? -- Please include part number.

This is going to depend on where the pcb is going, whether the hood has to extend in to the chassis, etc.
So, it's largely up to you and your needs, but you should verify in the data sheet for the part whether what you want to do is OK with that particular connector.
Note that the hang-over-the-edge design may impact the depanelization process more than the other option, so if you're having the boards populated and depanelized, it may cost a bit more.

When plugging a cable into a right-angle connector, sometimes the overmolding of the cable strikes the PCB edge before the cable fully mates, so the cable isn’t held in very well. Depending on the connector and cable design, this doesn’t always happen, but to be safe the PCB designer can place the connector so that it overhangs PCB edge.
If the data sheet has a recommended overhang, we use that number. Otherwise, our in-house design rule is to use an overhang of at least 0.5 mm (20 thou). Note that an in-house design rule is something our mechanical engineers made up, and not a something found in a MIL or IPC standard.
If this is going in a case, you might want to overhang the connector more. Too much overhang and the connector may no longer be well supported, or you might violate the copper to board-edge requirements of the PCB fabricator.

Whatever you do, you need strain relief. Strain happens when the cable is pushed or pulled that moves the connector in a way that can create strain on the connector. This strain should not have to be carried by the connector itself. The shroud with a chassis inlet can help with this. Another thing I've done in the past is have the cable zip tied to some thing so if the user pulls on the cable it doesn't translate to the PCB and rip the connector off the PCB.
Overhanging the connector makes it so the connector can bend more and can't take as much strain because the cable acts like a bigger lever, if you have a chassis then the connector will bend until it hits the chassis and that will reduce strain.
Also make sure in manufacturing there is enough solder on the connector mounts, I have seen connectors come off boards with insufficient solder.

The datasheet is not exactly well written, let alone well translated... but it appears they give an answer.

Presumably by the one line, they mean Circuit Board [edge].  Unfortunately, they don't give a dimension...
You also appear to be missing two pads.  Which, they don't dimension at all, nor indicate what preferred soldering location(s) on the shell are...
Probably, these pads don't matter much, and something roughly to scale will suffice.  I like to add vias to such pads, as the soldering isn't very important; while the mechanical strength is.  Vias improve peel strength.
If the figure is to scale, and taking centerline of the oval thru-pads as datum: the board edge is y = 2.0mm, and the shell SMT pads are 1.2 x 0.8mm, with centers x = ±1.6mm and y = 1.4mm.
